# Error al subir un archivo con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando cargar archivos a un directoria y guardar la info en la base de datos, pero
tengo estos errores:

> Notice: Undefined index: usuario in... on line 6

> Notice: Undefined index: archivo in... on line 10

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in.. on line 10

> Notice: Undefined index: archivo in.. on line 12

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in.. on line 12

```
<?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "tuvieja", "pruebas");




/* liena 6 */ $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');

$dir = "inv/";
/* liena 10 */ $ruta = $dir . $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

/* liena 12 */ if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $ruta)){

    $insertar = "INSERT INTO archivo (usuario, factura, fecha) VALUES ($usuario, $ruta, $fecha)";
    $ress = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
    if($ress){
        echo "Factura cargada";
    } else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="usuario" autocomplete="off" placeholder="USUARIO ID"><br><br>
<input type="file" name="archivo"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar Archivo">
</form>
```

Alguna ayuda? Agradezco de antemano!

Comment: Es porque en algunos caso dichas variables ```$_POST``` no están definido, por ejemplo la línea 6 si la cambias así: ```$usuario = $_POST['usuario'] ?: '';``` te soluciona esa línea, aun así deberías envolver todo el código dentro de ```if (isset($_POST['btn'])) { // tu codigo  $conexion ....  }```, es decir, si $_POST existe entra al bucle. para ello debes añadir el atributo ```name``` al **submit**, ejemplo, ```<input type="submit" name='btn' value="Enviar Archivo">```, así también sabrá diferenciar si tienes más formularios en la misma página.

Comment: @DBE Tu comentario parece más una respuesta, aunque no hay reporte contra esta mala práctica, te recomiendo que si vas a responder, lo hagas en la sección correcta.

Comment: @Excorpion es solo un comentario de ayuda, lo puedes añadir a tu respuesta si quieres. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Los errores lo dicen claramente...
Indices no definidos y no se puede acceder al array.

Lo primero que debes hacer es verificar si los datos que estas enviando, se están recibiendo.
Si no se están recibiendo el problema es del archivo que los envia.

Las variables que estás intentando leer son las sgtes

```
$_POST['usuario'];
$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']
```

Para verificarlas y cargarlas a una variable, debes hacer, como te dicen en los comentarios, ver si estan definidas. Esto lo puedes aplicar para todas.

```
if(isset($_POST['usuario']) && empty($_POST['usuario'])){ //Verifico si la variable enviada está siendo recibida y que no sea vacía
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario']; //Cargo la variable
}else{
    echo "No se han recibido los datos de usuario </br>"; //Sino, muestro un error
}
```

Incluso, para saltarte el caso a caso, puedes simplemente hacer:

```
var_dump($_POST); //Revisas si POST fue cargado con algo
var_dump($FILES); //Revisas si FILES fue cargado con algo
```

Comment: Aclarar que el var_dump es para hacer debug del escenario en desarrollo, mientras que el isset es una validación que perfectamente puede vivir en un entorno productivo